# Need to Customize the UIButton with attributed string as shown in figure

Tags: iphone, ios8, uistoryboard, xcode6.1

Hello I want the create the Keypad as shown in picture. I have added buttons but don't know how to customize the UIButton as shown below in following link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt4uu.png

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated .....

Answer (score 2):

We can set attributed string for button `titleLabel`.

```
 NSString *string = @" 6\n MNO";  
 NSMutableAttributedString *attribString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:string];

//specify proper font for letters on button. 
[attribString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8] range:NSMakeRange(attribString.length -3, 3)];

//similarly add attribute for number also if needed.
self.attribButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[self.attribButton setAttributedTitle:attribString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks Cristeena , Anil. I tried this solution. But it doesn't work. I put the above code in initWithNumber:(NSInteger)number andString:(NSString *)letters method in subclasses UIbutton class.

Answer (score 0):

@Christeena John, Thanks for quick reply,

The UI looks like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mvq4k.png

I have used this code snippet from the github :- 
https://github.com/kosyloa/PinPad

and updated UI a little bit as per my requirement.

Comment: @Christeena John,@Anil Varghese, The problem solved. Put code above from Christeena in DrawRect instead of init method. It works and shows up the attributed string. Thanks Christeena.